# Randomize array for wordpress featured image

Tags: arrays, wordpress, random

I am using a code to set the featured image for posts in wordpress. This part I want to change:

```
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '464');
```

It works fine but the think is that it is using the attachment id 464 from the media as the featured image for every post.
What I want is to have a few attachments ids and for each post randomize these ids and set it as the featured image.

I tried the following:

```
$images = array(
    '646',
    '1059',
    '1058',
    '1057'
);

$image = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

And then to set the image it would be:

```
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $image);
```

But it doesn't work. Probabily the way it is wrote is wrong or something...
How should it be codded so that it sets the featured images from randomizing these attachments ids?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin/function appears to do what you are looking for, but in a slightly different way.

Perhaps it will help.

http://stcroixsolution.com/auto-feature-plugi/